# Function is not a function after change from JQuery 1.4.2 to latest 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, upgrade

I have changed JQuery library from 1.4.2 to 1.7.2 for one project where we use JQTouch and JQT segmentedControl componente.

After JQuery upgrade application stops on this error in Firebug:

jQT.getSCValue is not a function

This is library causing problems
http://www.webwrx.sk/clients/jqt.segmentedControl.js

I havent changed JQTouch library, neither its components. Is it possible that newer JQuery somehow works somehow differently with external libraries?

Or do I need somehow to register this additional libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: Contact the developer of those plugins and see if updates are available.  A lot has changed with jQuery since 1.4.2.

Comment: I hate slamming fellow developers, but I wouldn't use a plugin written by [somebody whose own website](http://www.davidkaneda.com) causes Safari to consistently crash hard.

Comment: Problem is that I took project which uses this plugin. Cant say I am happy now.

Comment: Best case, there is a newer version available for jQuery 1.7.  Worst case, you'll have to go through the plugin, line-by-line looking for outdated methods.

Comment: I am afraid I will have to find problem with the plugin. Or remove all instances of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest version of jQTouch, version 1, beta 4 RC which was released on March 31, 2012, so hopefully, it's fully compatible with jQuery 1.7.2

http://www.jqtouch.com/

Amazingly, the developer is not including a version number, or even a release date, in the copyright header of his files.  However, I found this online which may be newer (or older) than the one you already have...

[jqt.segmentedControl.js](http://www.kankado.com/dev/test/jqtouch/extensions/jqt.segmentedControl/jqt.segmentedControl.js)

Comment: Giving +1 even though not entirely helpful but developer of that plugin really sucks.